# travis-ci encrypt command is asking for login --pro

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to encrypt some signature details using travis cli:

```
travis encrypt SONATYPE_USERNAME=xxxx
```

I get an error saying :

```
not logged in, please run travis login --pro
```

Is it required to have a pro login to use encrypt? Can I not use org login and use this command?

Comment: I could not reproduce this behavior with the command that you used.

Please display the full command as you run it (you can obviously mask the repo name if you want), and, right after you executed the command, the output of:

    `travis report`

Comment: Also, try specifying the `--org` endpoint explicitly

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь: that works.. Please add this as an answer. ill accept it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To `encrypt`, Travis-CLI will require being logged in first. The `--pro` flag provided with the help string is a good default (`travis.com` (paid) users are more likely to use the CLI), but not strictly necessary and can be replaced with `--org`, which will use the `travis.org` (free) endpoint.

Comment: @Jacko A quick test proves you wrong. Do you have anything to support that?

Comment: Just to clarify, you need to add --org to the command. ex: ```travis encrypt-file --org [filename]```.  Tested in v1.8.8

Answer (score 0):

for https://travis-ci.org

```sh
travis login --org
travis encrypt <string> --org
```